# Angle between planes with x, y and z variables

Tags: analytic-geometry

**Problem:** Find the angle between the planes $3x-y+z-5=0$ and $x+2y+2z+2=0$.

We have been thought 1 formula for solving angles which is : Angle $= Arctan(\frac{m1-m2}{1+m1m2})$ but that is for parallel lines only and for equation with x and y only.

How to answer this kind of problem? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to find the angle between two vectors using their dot product?

Comment: @amd I used to but i've forgotten it now and also, didn't know we could apply it to analytic geometry. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the normal of each plane and then use the dot product
Let us consider normal of $3x-y+z-5=0$ as $P_1$ and

$x+2y+2z+2=0$ as $P_2$, then we have
$$\ P_1=(3,-1,1),\ P_2=(1,2,2)$$

The formula for finding the angle is $$P_1\cdot P_2=|P_1|\cdot|P_2|\cdot\cos(\theta)$$
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{P_1\cdot P_2}{|P_1|\cdot|P_2|}$$
$$|P_1|=\sqrt{3^2+(-1)^2+1^2}=\sqrt{9+1+1}=\sqrt{11}$$
$$|P_2|=\sqrt{1^2+2^2+2^2}=\sqrt{1+4+4}=\sqrt{9}=3$$
$$P_1\cdot P_2=3(1)+(-1)(2)+1(2)=3-2+2=3$$

Then,
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3}{3\cdot\sqrt{11}}$$

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}$$
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}$$
$$\theta=72.5^o$$

Comment: Thank you. Didn't occur to me that we could apply this to analytic geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the angle between two planes is similar to finding the angle between two vector (normal of the planes). The first plane is $3x-y+z-5=0$ has normal  $\overrightarrow n_0 =\langle 3, -1, 1 \rangle$. The second plane is $x+2y+2z+2=0$ has normal  $\overrightarrow n_1 =\langle 1, 2, 2 \rangle$.

To find the angle between two vectors we use the formula
$$cos(\theta)= \frac{\mathbf A \bullet \mathbf B}{|\mathbf A||\mathbf B|}$$
Insert A as $\overrightarrow n_0$ and B as $\overrightarrow n_1$.
$$\overrightarrow n_0 \bullet \overrightarrow n_1=3*1+(-1)*(2)+1(2) = 3$$
$$|\overrightarrow n_0| = \sqrt{3^2+(-1)^2+1^2}=\sqrt{11}$$
$$|\overrightarrow n_1| = \sqrt{1^2+2^2+2^2}=3$$
So,
$$cos(\theta)= \frac{3}{\sqrt{11}*3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}$$
Therefore

$$\theta= \arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}) \approx 1.26451896 rad$$
Relevant [Find the angle between two planes using their normal vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528909/find-the-angle-between-two-planes-using-their-normal-vectors)

Comment: What do we mean when we say a line equation or plane is normal?

Comment: @Jayce Normal of a plane is a vector that is perpendicular to the plane. Look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)